# Wp_query with 2 meta keys and array of meta values

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, loop, meta-query

Hi in my post_type=shop i have 2 meta keys and array of values

Custom fields

```
 Name           Values

 cu_status   pending,processing,completed

 cu_date     12-Jan-2016 , 13-Jan-2016, ......  any date in the same format date("d-M-Y")
```

Now i need to loop through all posts with cu_status =pending,processing and cu_date is between 12-Jan-2016 to 13-Apr-2016
What will the query ?

Iam very confused . For to get all post with status pending,processing I know the query

```
 $args = array(

        'post_type'         => 'shop',

        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'cu_status',
           'value' => array('pending','processing'),
           'compare' => 'IN',
           )
           ),
           'posts_per_page' => -1
                );
```

Pleases help to complete the query .

Comment: You haven't made this easy with the date format you're storing. Is there any option on the cards to change this to a numeric format e.g. `dmY`?

Comment: yes, i can change the date format when storing . Because it is my custom query .

Comment: could you please help to solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526268/sql-query-to-download-order-report-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'cu_status',
            'value'     => array( 'pending', 'processing' ),
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'cu_date',
            'value'     => array( '2016-01-12', '2016-01-13' ),
            'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'      => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you . but for me it is not working .  'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
           'key' => 'cu_status',
           'value' => array( 'pending', 'processing' ),
           'compare' => 'IN',
           ),
     array(
     
     'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
     'key' => 'cu_date',
           'value' => '04-02-2016',
           'compare' => '>=',
     
     ),
     array(
           'key' => 'cu_date',
           'value' => '04-03-2016',
           'compare' => '<=',
           ))
     
           )  This is working .

Comment: But it is not correct also

Comment: I store cu_date in (31-02-2016) format . Please help .

Comment: I get the it . Your code is working .  i Changed the date format into 2016-01-13

Comment: Could you please see this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color

Comment: Yes indeed, you need to insert the date in the right format. I am glad that I was able to help.

Comment: Really thank you friend  :) . Could you please see this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color  .Please

Comment: Could you please check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263072/wordpress-post-filter-using-ajax